# How to copy multiple directories to one directory in Node

Tags: node.js, fs-extra

I'm looking for something like..

```
fs.copy([dir1,dir2], 'destDirString').then(() => {
cb();
});
```

Is there an easy way to copy two directories' contents to another dir in Node? I have two NCP commands now, want to condense.

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for  [merge-dirs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-dirs)

Usage:

```
var mergedirs = require('merge-dirs');

// copy folder/a into folder/b
mergedirs('/folder/a', '/folder/b');
// copy folder/a into folder/b with conflict resolution 'overwrite'
mergedirs('/folder/a', '/folder/b', 'overwrite');
// copy folder/a into folder/b with conflict resolution 'ask'
mergedirs('/folder/a', '/folder/b', 'ask');
// copy folder/a into folder/b with conflict resolution 'skip'
mergedirs('/folder/a', '/folder/b', 'skip');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. It only copies one folder. I want to copy two into one.

Comment: You can use it. But it will do it simultaneous the same step one by one.